# Which version of MS Office is required to develop apps?

Tags: c#, ms-office, development-environment

I am considering which version of MS Office 2016 to use for developing office apps.  I will be using Visual Studio Community 2015.  I would like to know which suite version of MS Office 2016 is compatible with developing apps.  I am worried that using a "Home and Student" version will not work with Visual Studio 2015 Community, like the "Professional" version will.

Also, is it possible to develop with Office 365 or is the desktop version required.

Comment: What apps will you be developing for? Word and Excel? Access? Are you making a Project add-in? Are you making a VSTO add-in? This doesn't seem like the kind fo question others can really answer though. What are *your* needs?

Comment: In a word, to answer your question: Yes.  I will use this to develop all kinds of applications.  I don't want to be limited based on a uninformed choice before I get started.  So yes "Project add-ins" (Excel , Outlook, Word, Access ...) and yes "VSTO add-ins"

Comment: This question is off-topic here. We do not recommend software, whether it's for programming or not, and we do not provide pre-sales support for MS products. If you need information about available features in each version, check the MS web site for the product or contact Microsoft sales.

Comment: H/S will have access to fewer MS Office applications, but if you only want Word and Excel, you're good to go. It's not about developability, it's about what products you have access to. The only main difference is that older versions of Office (I think <14) have different interfaces.

Comment: Thanks Shannon,  This is where I was trying to go with question.  @Ken: I am not asking for a recommendation on which MS product is best.  I am asking about what is required to develop.  Shannon gets it.

Comment: You're asking us to provide you with a recommendation for which version you will need for development. It's the equivalent of asking us which computer is best to use for development; it's not a programming related question, and it's not appropriate here. MS can provide you with pre-sales support to answer your questions about the different versions.

Comment: @Ken You seem to be interpreting this as you like.  See BradleyDotNET's answer, as the interpretation is closest to what I mean.  I did use the word "recommendation" but, I just need to know which versions are compatible.  This is a development question, it is not subjective, and it does not ask for an opinion.  Nonetheless, I have reworded the question even though I already have a valid answer.

Comment: You keep debating, but the question apparently reads the same as I've interpreted it to others, as the question is closed. You're asking us for which features are available in different versions of a **non-programming related product**, and MS can answer questions about the features of each version. You can debate it all you want, but according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines, it's off-topic here. I wasn't asking for a discussion, anyway; IMO, it's off-topic, and I voted to close it as such. The explanation of why I did so was intended as a courtesy; it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have access to the product in order to test your add-in (this is true even before Office 2016). So purchase the edition that contains the products you want to develop for.

That being said, many of the office apps are available for free as part of Office Online, and as long as you are willing to develop web-compatible add-ins, you don't need to buy anything.

Comment: OK good to know.  I was not aware I could use the free online versions.  I believe you have answered my question.